# Access wpf control from DataGrid DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid control, i also have a DataTemplate (CheckBox) control in it, which is shown below

```
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50" MinWidth="20"  >
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <!--<TextBlock Text="Manage" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FF666666" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0" />-->
                                                        <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                                                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox_CheckAllStuRow" Width="20" Height="auto" Checked="chkBox_CheckAllStuRow_Checked" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox_CheckStuRow" Width="20" Height="20"  />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="*" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding f_name}" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="*" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding l_name}"  />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Phone No" Width="*" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding phone}"   />

                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="250" >
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Manage" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FF666666" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0" />
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                                            <Button x:Name="btn_ViewStu"  Content="View" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="27" Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource ActiveButtonStyle}" Width="65" Click="btn_ViewStu_Click"  />
                                                            <Button x:Name="btn_DeleteStu" Content="Delete" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="27" Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource DangerButtonStyle}" Width="65" Click="btn_DeleteStu_Click"  />
                                                            <Button x:Name="btn_withDrwStu" Content="Withdraw" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="27" Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource DangerButtonStyle}" Width="70" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

What i want a achieve now, is to access the variable name of the check-box control, from my C# Code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify why you need the name of the checkbox? It sounds as a bad practice for WPF.

Comment: Every row in the DataGrid under a column is filled with a CheckBox, and the column header also has a CheckBox. All i wanted is when the column header CheckBox is checked, then all the CheckBox in the Rows under the CheckBox Column will be Checked Also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
List<string> chBoxName = new List<string>();
foreach (CheckBox tb in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(Window))
{
    chBoxName.Add(tb.Name);
}
```

The **chBoxName** Property has all the Checkbox Names in the type of `List<string>`.

The Helper Method is

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but its giving an error from here (Window) in the foreach statement.  Please help, what else can i do.